Efficient Computation of Third-Order Derivatives Using PyTorch for High-Dimensional Inputs
I am trying to compute third-order derivatives $f_{ijk} $ for
$i<j<k$ of a scalar function   with respect to its input vector ,x ,with 2000 variables using PyTorch. So far I was able to find both f_{iii} and f_{ijj} for $ j\neq i$  (takes something like 23 seconds to finds all the derivatives of the form $f_{ijk}$) .Additionally For some reasons I can't calculate $f_{ijk} $ (it takes too much times and then it crashes.
So far I wrote the code below.
import torch
from torch.autograd.functional import hessian
import numpy as np


torch.manual_seed(0)
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

n = 2000
k = 1

# Define the tensors on the GPU
a = torch.randn(k, n, device=device)
b = torch.randn(k, device=device)
x0 = torch.randn(n, device=device, requires_grad=True) * 1/100

def f(x):
    return torch.sum(torch.exp(torch.matmul(a, x) + b))

# Compute f(x) at x0
f_x = f(x0)

# Compute all third derivatives at once using vmap
# First derivative (gradient)
grad = torch.autograd.grad(f_x, x0, create_graph=True)[0]

hessian = torch.autograd.functional.hessian(f, x0, create_graph=True)


# Initialize tensors for storing results
f_iii = torch.zeros(n, device=device)
f_iij = torch.zeros(n, n, device=device)

# Compute second derivatives for each component
for i in range(n):
    hess_i = torch.autograd.grad(grad[i], x0, create_graph=True)[0]
    
    # Compute third derivatives for this i
    third = torch.autograd.grad(hess_i[i], x0, retain_graph=True)[0]
    
    f_iii[i] = third[i]
    f_iij[i] = third  # This gives us all j derivatives for fixed i

# Create the final f_iij tensor without duplicate computations
f_iij_final = []
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if i != j:
            f_iij_final.append(f_iij[i][j].item())

f_ijk=[]
for i in range(n):
  for j in range(i + 1, n):  # j > i
    for k in range(j + 1, n):  # k > j
      # Compute third derivative: ∂³f/∂x_i∂x_j∂x_k
      third_ijk = torch.autograd.grad(hessian[i,j], x0, retain_graph=True, create_graph=True)[0][k]
      f_ijk.append(third_ijk.item())



My questions are:

How can I optimize this code so i can find f_{i,j,k} and f_{i,i,j}
Are there alternative methods or libraries that can handle high-order derivatives for large-dimensional inputs more efficiently?

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!!
